# How to start a job in the stopped state?

Tags: bash, unix, shell, job-control

In `bash`, how can I initiate a job in a stopped state, as if I started it normally and then immediately pressed Ctrl-Z?

Or as if I had sent SIGSTOP to the process immediately, but without giving the process a chance to execute before it receives the SIGSTOP.

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/293632/how-do-i-start-a-process-in-suspended-state-under-linux ?

Comment: Yes, it's an exact duplicate.  Unfortunately the other question also has not been answered to my satisfaction.

Answer (score 6):

You can start a new subshell, immediatelly stop it, and then (i.e. after makint it run again) run your command. I used the $BASHPID variable to get the PID of the subshell, as $$ still returns the PID of the parent:

```
( kill -SIGSTOP $BASHPID; exec my_command )
```

Using `exec` here will cause the `my_command` process to use the same PID as the subshell.

Comment: Change it to
`( kill -SIGSTOP $BASHPID; exec my_command )` 
and I think we have a winner!

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is quite old, but just in case someone is looking for this functionality, like I was:

I recently added this to my LD_PRELOAD module collection (https://github.com/zardus/preeny). Using preeny, you can have a process suspend itself on startup:

```
# https://github.com/zardus/preeny
# cd preeny
# make
# LD_PRELOAD=x86_64-linux-gnu/startstop.so /bin/echo TEST
[1]+  Stopped    LD_PRELOAD=x86_64-linux-gnu/startstop.so /bin/echo TEST
# fg
TEST
```

Preeny suspends the process during library startup, before `main()` is called.

Comment: Hi Zardus, and welcome to Super User. No worries about answering an old question. This is an interesting approach!

Comment: This approach is nice, because it actually loads the binary. However, I guess other constructor functions can run before preeny.

Comment: Yes... I haven't found a way to control the execution order of constructors, unfortunately.